# Operation less than or higher than type data time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Less than operation in time data type

I want get value `clock_in >= '07:30' and clock_in <= '12:00'`

I use query :

```
SELECT clock_in,
       Timetable
FROM kkpsurabaya
WHERE timetable = 'sabtu'
   OR Timetable = 'minggu'
   AND clock_in >= '07:30'
   AND clock_in <= '11:00';
```

But that no work still show data having time 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY the below query.

```
  SELECT clock_in,Timetable 
  FROM  kkpsurabaya 
  WHERE timetable  IN ('sabtu' ,'minggu' )
          and clock_in between ( convert (TIME,'07:30:00 AM') and convert( TIME,'11:00:00 AM'))
```